# Fastest way to determine whether a string contains a real or integer value

Tags: c++, optimization, parsing

I'm trying to write a function that is able to determine whether a string contains a real or an integer value.

This is the simplest solution I could think of:

```
int containsStringAnInt(char* strg){
  for (int i =0; i < strlen(strg); i++) {if (strg[i]=='.') return 0;}
  return 1;
}
```

But this solution is really slow when the string is long... Any optimization suggestions?
Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. As mentioned below, it incorrectly identifies 1e-6 as an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strlen, which means you are not worried about unicode. In that case why to use strlen or strchr, just check for '\0' (Null char)

```
int containsStringAnInt(char* strg){ 

  for (int i =0;strg[i]!='\0'; i++) {
      if (strg[i]=='.') return 0;}   
  return 1; }
```

Only one parsing through the string, than parsing through the string in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This answer is effectively the same as my answer (below), and should have nearly identical performance.

Comment: No, this might be a partial parsing, while your code parses teh entire string atleast once for strlen, which is essentially searches for '\0'

Comment: return (NULL != strchr(strg,'.'));

Comment: strchr() is a better option since library functions are frequently optimized assembly whereas this code would not compile that way.

Answer (score 7):

What's the syntax of your real numbers?

1e-6 is valid C++ for a literal, but will be passed as integer by your test.

Answer (score 3):

Is your string hundreds of characters long? Otherwise, don't care about any possible performance issues.
The only inefficiency is that you are using strlen() in a bad way, which means a lot of iterations over the string (inside strlen). For a simpler solution, with the same time complexity (O(n)), but probably slightly faster, use strchr().

Comment: Yes, you should use strchr() for searching - library functions are often written in optimized assembly code so they outgun simple C-compiled versions. +1.

Comment: As was the point with my answer, it will not matter so you took a good decision (upvoting) for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not take into account exponential notation of reals (1E7, 1E-7 are both doubles)

Use strtol() to try to convert the string to integer first; it will also return the first position in the string where the parsing failed (this will be '.' if the number is real). If the parsing stopped at '.', use strtod() to try to convert to double.  Again, the function will return the position in the string where the parsing stopped.

Don't worry about performance, until you have profiled the program. Otherwise, for fastest possible code, construct a regular expression that describes acceptable syntax of numbers, and hand-convert it first into a FSM, then into highly optimized code.

Comment: "(this will be '.' if the number is real)" Not if it's "1e-7" (to use your example)

Comment: also note german locales where numbers are "1,0". i had problems with that previously, until i figured out the "," in the number is causing them :)

Answer (score 1):

So the standard note first, please don't worry about performance too much if not profiled yet :)

I'm not sure about the manual loop and checking for a dot. Two issues

- Depending on the locale, the dot can actually be a "," too (here in Germany that's the case :)
- As others noted, there is the issue with numbers like 1e7

Previously I had a version using sscanf here. But measuring performance showed that sscanf is is significantly slower for bigger data-sets. So I'll show the faster solution first (Well, it's also a whole more simple. I had several bugs in the sscanf version until I got it working, while the strto[ld] version worked the first try):

```
enum {
    REAL,
    INTEGER,
    NEITHER_NOR
};

int what(char const* strg){ 
    char *endp;
    strtol(strg, &endp, 10);
    if(*strg && !*endp)
        return INTEGER;
    strtod(strg, &endp);
    if(*strg && !*endp)
        return REAL;
    return NEITHER_NOR;
}
```

<sub>Just for fun, here is the version using sscanf:</sub>

```
int what(char const* strg) {
    // test for int
    { 
        int d;     // converted value
        int n = 0; // number of chars read
        int rd = std::sscanf(strg, "%d %n", &d, &n);
        if(!strg[n] && rd == 1) {
            return INTEGER;
        }
    }
    // test for double
    { 
        double v;     // converted value
        int n = 0; // number of chars read
        int rd = std::sscanf(strg, "%lf %n", &v, &n);
        if(!strg[n] && rd == 1) {
            return REAL;
        }
    }
    return NEITHER_NOR;
}
```

I think that should work. Have fun.

Test was done by converting test strings (small ones) randomly 10000000 times in a loop:

- 6.6s for `sscanf`
- 1.7s for `strto[dl]`
- 0.5s for `manual looping` until "."

Clear win for `strto[ld]`, considering it will parse numbers correctly I will praise it as the winner over manual looping. Anyway, 1.2s/10000000 = 0.00000012 difference roughly for one conversion isn't all that much in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Strlen walks the string to find the length of the string.

You are calling strlen with every pass of the loop.  Hence, you are walking the string way many more times than necessary.  This tiny change should give you a huge performance improvement:

```
int containsStringAnInt(char* strg){
  int len = strlen(strg);
  for (int i =0; i < len; i++) {if (strg[i]=='.') return 0;}
  return 1;
}
```

Note that all I did was find the length of the string once, at the start of the function, and refer to that value repeatedly in the loop.

Please let us know what kind of performance improvement this gets you.

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron, with your way also you are traversing the string twice. Once within strlen, and once again in for loop. 
Best way for ASCII string traversing in for loop is to check for Null char in the loop it self. Have a look at my answer, that parses the string only once within for loop, and may be partial parsing if it finds a '.' prior to end. that way if a string is like 0.01xxx (anotther 100 chars), you need not to go till end to find the length.

Comment: True, true.
Ultimately, your code walks a fraction of the string (to a max of the whole string).
My code walks the whole string once + a fraction (to a max of the whole string).

In big O-notation, both codes run in O(length) time, but yours has a smaller constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int containsStringAnInt(char* strg){ 
    if (atof(strg) == atoi(strg))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```